# Async issue on getting values from the server

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, alamofire, nsoperationqueue

In my `viewDidLoad` I do:

```
// Get Profile Info
    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock { () -> Void in
        let getMyProfileURL = "\(self.property.host)\(self.property.getMyProfile)"
        print(getMyProfileURL)
        Alamofire.request(.POST, getMyProfileURL, parameters: self.property.profileParameteres, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in
            do {
                let json = JSON(data: response.data!)

                if json["user"].count > 0 {
                    self.profileDetails.append(ProfileDetailsModel(json: json["user"]))
                }
            }
        }

        print(self.profileDetails[0].firstName)
    }
```

so, when I want to get the `firstName` from the array:

```
 print(self.profileDetails[0].firstName)
```

my app crashes with the error:

```
fatal error: Array index out of range
```

My array is empty. I've used `NSOperationQueue` for it, but I still get empty array and crash. How can I fix this problem and access my **filled** array from anywhere in my controller, not only inside the Alamofire block?

Comment: If the array is empty it may mean that you're not getting any response from the server. Or your key to access the json is wrong.

Comment: Also your json may be being returned as an array in itself, so try something like `json[0]["user"]` to access the first one etc.

Comment: Try `print(json)` to see what sort of data structure you're working with.

Comment: @Phoen1xUK I know what data I have. That's not my problem. My problem is accessing it from other places in my controller

Comment: Ah yeah, after rereading your code and looking at the other answers, I can see that you're trying to access the array before the request is completed since the Alamofire request will be asynchronous and the print will be performed straight away.

Answer (score 1):

The Request is Asynchronous, it will only fill the `self.profileDetails` array when it receive an answer, and execute the `completionHandler` block.

In your code, you call to execute the Asynchronous task, it will run in another thread, and the app goes back to the next operation and immediately try to access the `self.profileDetails`, with at the time may still be `nil`.

You must wait the completion handler block finish to fill the array, and then access the data.

The code of @Md.Muzahidul Islam , will work as you want.

Comment: but I want to achieve it from other places, too. I do not want to access it only from the Alamofire block

Comment: @JohnDoe, after its complete, the data it will be always available in the array. You can have a flag to check if the data was loaded, or call other functions to inform the end of the task

Comment: I have a problem with my collectionView cells count. I get nil there when I'm trying to set it's value from my `self.profileDetails.first?.myArrayThere.count`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you give more details about? I did not understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Now it will work fine

```
  NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock { () -> Void in
        let getMyProfileURL = "\(self.property.host)\(self.property.getMyProfile)"
        print(getMyProfileURL)
        Alamofire.request(.POST, getMyProfileURL, parameters: self.property.profileParameteres, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in
            do {
                let json = JSON(data: response.data!)

                if json["user"].count > 0 {
                    self.profileDetails.append(ProfileDetailsModel(json: json["user"]))
                }
            }
        print(self.profileDetails[0].firstName)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest refactoring your code to move this to a function outside of your `viewDidLoad` and then adding your own completion handler. Something like:

```
func getData(completion: () -> Void) {
    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock { () -> Void in
        let getMyProfileURL = "\(self.property.host)\(self.property.getMyProfile)"
        print(getMyProfileURL)
        Alamofire.request(.POST, getMyProfileURL, parameters: self.property.profileParameteres, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in
            do {
                let json = JSON(data: response.data!)

                if json["user"].count > 0 {
                    self.profileDetails.append(ProfileDetailsModel(json: json["user"]))
                }
            }
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` you can call it with its completion handler to access the data outside of the Alamofire block after it's finished, e.g.

```
getData() {
    print(self.profileDetails[0].firstName)
}
```

Comment: I have a problem with my collectionView cells count. I get `nil` there when I'm trying to set it's value from my `self.profileDetails.first?.myArrayThere.count`. How can I fix it?